# Get all possible palindromes in C#

Tags: c#, strings, palindrome

As the title says, the goal is to get all the possible [palindromes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome) of a string in C#:

```
public static bool IsPalindrome(this string source)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < source.Length / 2; i++)
    {
        if(source[i] != source[source.Length - 1 - i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

public static IEnumerable<string> GetPossiblePalindromes(this string source, int maxPossibleChanges, IEnumerable<char> alphabet)
{
    var executionStack = new Stack<Tuple<string, int>>();
    executionStack.Push(Tuple.Create(source, 0));
    int maxChanges = Math.Min(maxPossibleChanges, source.Length);
    var generated = new HashSet<string>();
    generated.Add(source);

    if(maxPossibleChanges < 0)
    {
        yield break;
    }

    do
    {
        Tuple<string, int> currentRecord = executionStack.Pop();

        string currentString = currentRecord.Item1;
        if (currentString.IsPalindrome())
        {
            yield return currentString;
        }

        int currentNumberOfChanges = currentRecord.Item2;
        if (currentNumberOfChanges == maxChanges)
        {
            continue;
        }

        char[] chars = currentString.ToArray();
        foreach(char character in alphabet)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < currentString.Length; i++)
            {
                char old = chars[i];
                if(character == old)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                chars[i] = character;
                var newString = new string(chars);
                if (generated.Contains(newString))
                {
                    chars[i] = old;
                    continue;
                }
                generated.Add(newString);
                executionStack.Push(Tuple.Create(newString, currentNumberOfChanges + 1));
                chars[i] = old;
            }
        }
    } while (executionStack.Count > 0);

    yield break;
}
```

Case sensitivity is taken into account and there is a max number of changes one can make to the original string in order to make it a palindrome. Also, a 1 charactes string is not considered a palindrome.

I wanted to ask for a review. I'm more interested in performance reviews but all the other reviews are more than welcome.

Comment: Please include all methods written by you e.g `IsPalindrome` they also affect the performance of your program.

Comment: Also you need to provide more information on what specific palindromes do you consider. Is case sensitivity a thing ? Does a single character counts as a palindrome ?

Comment: @denis, I added some more info. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4):

First and foremost your code is solving a different problem from the one stated in the question *Get all the possible palindromes of a string* or at least that's what it looks like and as pointed in my comments you need to provide more details and context about the code.

I will try to make a few points concerning your existing code aside from it being overly-complicated :

1. Do you really need an iterator here ? What's the point of saving the state of this code ? You clearly want all the possible palindromes from a specified string which to me sounds like I would receive a `List<string>` containing all the palindromes in there.
2. Usually converting string to char array is redundant but if you really need to do that you are better off using `string.ToCharArray()` instead of `string.ToArray()` detailed explanation why is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37139124/7095916).
3. `Contains()` is O(n) operation so you should avoid it if possible
4. It might be a good idea to replace that `Tuple<string, int>` with a class, but I'm not sure what is the point of having it in the first place.

I will provide an alternative solution to the problem :

**Get all the possible palindromes of a string with length more than 1**.

First let's start by declaring a method that decides if a string is a palindrome.

```
private static bool IsPalindrome(string input)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        if (input[i] != input[input.Length - 1 - i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here we are making use of the fact that string is already a `char[]` and we can simply avoid the redundant call `ToCharArray()`. Also we are using only a single `for` loop and we are returning as soon as we find 2 different characters to increase performance.

This can also be converted to a one-liner using LINQ

```
private static bool IsPalindrome(string input)
{
    return !input.Where((t, i) => t != input[input.Length - 1 - i]).Any();
}
```

or with C# 6

```
private static bool IsPalindrome(string input) => !input.Where((t, i) => t != input[input.Length - 1 - i]).Any();
```

Next we need to actually make use of that method and get all of the possible palindromes of a string :

```
private static List<string> GetPalindromes(string source)
{
    List<string> subsets = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= source.Length; j++)
        {
            if (j - i > 1 && source[j - 1] == source[i])
            {
                string currentSubset = source.Substring(i, j - i);
                if (IsPalindrome(currentSubset))
                {
                    subsets.Add(currentSubset);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return subsets;
}
```

This chunk of code is what I would like to have as I explained in my first point but if you really need an iterator :

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetPalindromes(this string source)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= source.Length; j++)
        {
            if (j - i > 1 && source[j - 1] == source[i])
            {
                string currentSubset = source.Substring(i, j - i);
                if (IsPalindrome(currentSubset))
                {
                    yield return currentSubset;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your first `IsPalindrome` implementation it's enough to iterate up to `input.Length / 2`. So the next 2 LINQ one-liners are two times less efficient in the case if the `input` is palindrome.